# add view not supported

Tags: android, button

im new to android programming and i ran into a problem. here is the code snippet

```
nums = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.nums);
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText(i+"");
    b.setTextSize(15);
    b.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    b.setOnClickListener(numsClickHandler);
    nums.addView(b, 20, 20);
}
```

the problem occurs when it reaches `nums.addView(b, 20, 20);`

```
caused by: java.lang.unsupportedoperationexception: addView(View, int, layoutparams) is    
not supported in adapterview
```

Comment: sorry about the format, it said indent by 4 spaces which is what i did, but it didnt come out right...hopefully this helps http://i302.photobucket.com/albums/nn83/aznafro/code.png

Comment: Next time, simply highlight your code and press Crtl+K to create the code format here in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Error message is clear, `GridView` is an AdapterView which does not allow directly adding view to it, rather, it works like ListView that you need to supply an adapter to it, and in your adapter, provide the Views. The [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) tutorial may help.

Comment: ok so they way i understand it from looking at the example, since i dont have images to work with, im going to return a button view instead for the getView method to create the buttons?

Comment: yes, or inflate from an xml, you may need to look at ListView tutorial as well.

Answer (score 0):

To start, let's create a layout call grid_item.xml with:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="numberClick"
    android:textColor="@color/cyan"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

(and any other attributes that you want)

Next, to add new items in your grid with this layout, Adapter.add():

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.grid_item, new ArrayList<String>());
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    adapter.add(String.valueOf(i));
grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Of course, you'll also need a method called `numberClick` from the XML `onClick` attribute:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // add your numClickHandler code here
}
```

Comment: im getting an "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix" with the <Button

Comment: You need to add the attribute: `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
nums = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.nums);
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
    Button b = new Button(this);
   -->** b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));**
    b.setText(i+"");
    b.setTextSize(15);
    b.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    b.setOnClickListener(numsClickHandler);
    nums.addView(b);
}
```